# Set up a basic D3DXQUATERNION

Tags: directx, quaternion

I'm trying to set up a D3DXQUATERNION to operate a rotation of 90 degrees around the Y axis.

I tried in the following way:

```
D3DXQUATERNION tempRot1(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, cos(XM_PIDIV2/2));
```

because in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205402(v=vs.85).aspx) they write that the fourth component, w, is defined as:

```
q.w = cos(theta/2)
```

But I'm afraid I didn't understand correctly, since the rotation is not what I expected.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i didn't read carefully enough the documentations, it states that:

```
q.x = sin(theta/2) * axis.x
q.y = sin(theta/2) * axis.y
q.z = sin(theta/2) * axis.z
q.w = cos(theta/2)
```

so in my case i had to write:

```
D3DXQUATERNION tempRot1(0.0f, sin(XM_PIDIV2 / 2), 0.0f, cos(XM_PIDIV2 / 2));
```

Comment: or if you want to avoid the trig functions tempRot1(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); and normalize.

Comment: mmm, an interesting suggestion, i guess it works only because i've chosen a particular angle, right?

Comment: yeah `sin(XM_PIDIV2 / 2) == sqrt(0.5)`